# How to change shortcut for Undo in WebStorm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

I have a German keyboard which I then changed to layout to English.

The problem with German keyboard is that `Y` and `Z` is replaced. So doing <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> was a torture to me. And now I've changed the layout, I am supposed to `Undo` with <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> but WebStorm doesn't recognize it and uses <kbd>Ctrl + Y</kbd> (because that was the way in German keyboard as Y was Z actually).

What to do?

Comment: apparently, german keyboard has always issues. there are many tickets open for it, here is one of them https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003403200-WARNING-2019-1-German-Keyboard-Broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap and then you can redefine anything you choose.

Comment: now I changed it to Ctrl+Y and it works when I push Ctrl+Z as intended. but why the .. does it still say Ctrl+Y ? o.O

Comment: When you press Z on your keyboard, do you get Z in ordinary typing?